# Tomcat - SEVERE Error during starting static Resources ( A war which has been deleted purposefully )

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Yesterday i have downloaded a sample DWR War file net and deployed it inside Tomcat to test .

And today  after deleting it inside the Tomcat - Webapps and also  inside work\Catalina\localhost directroy .

I am getting the floowing error under Server Console , during Server Start up .

```
Jan 6, 2012 3:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\webapps\DWRExample does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Jan 6, 2012 3:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jan 6, 2012 3:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jan 6, 2012 3:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/DWRExample] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 6, 2012 3:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/DWRExample] has not been started
```

Please tell me how to handle this

Answer (score 7):

Check the folder `C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\conf\Catalina\localhost` for a file `DWRExample.xml`; it if exists, delete it.