# SEVERE: Error starting static Resources

Tags: tomcat

I am trying Spring tutorials. I developed one project and later deleted because it contained errors. In new project whenever i start Tomcat it is giving me SEVERE: Error starting static Resources.
I tried previous solutions given to this question
[Tomcat - SEVERE Error during starting static Resources ( A war which has been deleted purposefully )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756097/tomcat-severe-error-during-starting-static-resources-a-war-which-has-been-de/33777684#33777684)

But even after deleting that folder from C:\Users\A603388\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost  it still persists everytime i run apache tomacat.
As suggested in answer i couldn't find Spring_a.xml file.

Error-log is as follows:

```
Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\A603388\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Spring_a does not exist or is not a readable directory
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5055)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5235)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```